# ¿como sabe un formulario a que controlador tiene que enviar los datos?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

tengo una duda. En esta plantilla de twig se muestra un formulario.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello CrearUsuarioController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<style>
    .example-wrapper { margin: 1em auto; max-width: 800px; width: 95%; font: 18px/1.5 sans-serif; }
    .example-wrapper code { background: #F5F5F5; padding: 2px 6px; }
</style>

<div class="example-wrapper">
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Guardar') }}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

de manera que cuando pulsas el boton guardar envia los datos para que sean modificados en la base de datos. Pero no veo por ningun sitio a que controlador se tienen que enviar los datos para que estos sean tratados. ¿como sabe a que controlador tiene que enviar los datos dicho formulario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por defecto el formulario se envía a la misma ruta donde se encuentra el mismo, es decir tu controlador se encuentra en la misma ruta; si deseas especificar la ruta a un controlador diferente lo puedes hacer especificando el path en el action del formulario.

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('ruta_controlador')}) }}
```

puedes ver mas informacion en este sitio:
https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/form/action_method.html